# handlebars: conditionally add attribute

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a select element with options, like this

```
<select dropdown multiple class="dropdown" name="color">
        {{#each colors}}
            <option value="{{value}}" {{isSelected parentColor id}}>{{title}}></option>
        {{/each}}
</select>
```

I'm using the following handlebars helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isSelected', function(input, color) {
    return input === color ? 'selected' : '';
});
```

The problem is that the `selected` attribute doesn't show up on any of the `option` element, but when I place a `console.log` in the handlebar helper I do see that one matches (input === color === true). Any ideas what I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a working example of what is described,

http://jsfiddle.net/rtLGR/

**hbs**

```
<h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 

    <select dropdown multiple class="dropdown" name="color">
        {{#each colors}}
            <option value="{{value}}" {{isSelected parentColor id}}>{{title}}</option>
        {{/each}}
</select>
</script>
```

**js**

```
var source = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = {
    colors: [
        {id:1,value:1,title:"red",parentColor:2},
        {id:2,value:2,title:"green",parentColor:2},
        {id:3,value:3,title:"blue",parentColor:1}
    ]
};


Handlebars.registerHelper('isSelected', function (input, color) {
    return input === color ? 'selected' : '';
});

$('body').append(template(data));
```